# Apache graceful restart - Does it affect current PHP script execution

Tags: php, apache, restart

I had been reading about Apache graceful restart.

```
apachectl -k graceful
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/stopping.html#graceful

> The USR1 or graceful signal causes the parent process to advise the
>   children to exit after their current request (or to exit immediately
>   if they're not serving anything).

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/artic...estart-apache/

> ...meaning that anyone who is in the middle of downloading something
>   will continue to be able to download it.

If a long running PHP script is currently being executed (eg: processing a large image), will graceful restart allow it to be completed or will it hinder its execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be completed because the Apache child process is busy serving the response for the customers request and waits for PHP to finish the response.